# A C++ program that is abour cerr and clog runs differently in Clion and in terminal

Tags: c++, iostream, clion

I am trying to get use of `cerr` and `clog` instead of `cout` to give out error message. But I met a problem. Below is a simplified version.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "first" << endl;
        cerr << "second" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the result was

```
1
first
second
2
second
first
3
second
first
4
first
second
5
second
first
```

However, if I use g++ on Win10's cmd to compile and run, it was fine.

```
1
first
second
2
first
second
3
first
second
4
first
second
5
first
second
```

So I start to doubt that there are some certain settings that make the Clion inner compile&run environment differ from g++. But I am not sure.
Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: It's an unfortunate result of the buffering done internally by the "console" of CLion and the buffering of the standard streams (or rather the lack of buffering for `std::cerr`).

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, so can you describe in detail? And could you give some instructions on how to fix the probem with Clion if possible? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things under the hood (SPD mentioned some in the comment, but not all - there is a pty-pipe in the middle). But this just work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        cout.flush();
        cerr.flush();
        cout << "first" << endl;
        cout.flush();
        cerr << "second"<< endl;
        cerr.flush();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Read more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).

Comment: It still doesn't work on Clion. The problem is not about the codes. My original codes work well on terminal, but not on Clion. SPD's answer's given me an idea that it is probably because the console in Clion have some different settings, though I am still not very clear.